# Google's place autocomplete for android keeps giving me "Can't load search results"

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm designing an app that uses maps and requires users to input destinations.i added the PlaceAutoCompleteFragment in the xml

```
fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"         android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />
```

And this is what is in my java

`PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);




    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());



        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });`

When I try searching it says:"Can't load search results".What should I do after this?

Comment: This is happening for me intermittently. It's very difficult to fix when it does happen. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Josh Smith Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Anyone with the solution on this ?

Answer (score -2):

The [autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/) widget is a search dialog with built-in autocomplete functionality.

Use [`PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder) to create an intent to launch the autocomplete widget as an intent. After setting the optional parameters, call `build(Activity)` and pass the intent to `startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)`.

```
int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
...
try {
    Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).build(this);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    // TODO: Handle the error.
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    // TODO: Handle the error.
}
```

To receive notification when a user has selected a place, your app should override the activity's onActivityResult(), checking for the request code you have passed for your intent, as shown in the following example.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());    
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't change the outcome.The only difference is it launches a separate autocomplete activity.But the result is the same.Just gives me "Can't load search results"